# symfony 2 different errors same form, same input

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

I am using the same form (builder and entity) on two different pages of my application (one user facing, one admin). However I am experiencing an odd error when I test both of these pages.

The file field in my builders look like this.

```
$builder        
->add('companyLogo','file',
    array(
        'constraints' => array(
            new Assert\Image(
                array(
                    'maxSize' => '2Mi',
                    'minWidth' => 50,
                    'minHeight' => 50,
                    'mimeTypes' => array(
                        'image/png', 
                        'image/jpg', 
                        'image/jpeg', 
                        'image/gif'
                        ),
                    'mimeTypesMessage' => 'Please upload a valid JPG, GIF or PNG.'
                    )
                ),
            ),
        )
    )
```

When I tested the forms by attempting to upload a small (<500kb) pdf file one form displays the errors of "Please upload a valid JPG, GIF or PNG." and "This file is not a valid image." as expected. The other form (using the same builder, theme and entity) displays "This file is too large." twice.

I have been unable to find any indication as to why I would be getting this error and more to the point why two different copies of the form would be throwing different errors for the same input.

Any suggestions on why this is happening and how I can avoid it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your platform?

Comment: I'm using Symfony 2.7.5

Comment: Platform, not a Symfony version. I mean OS, httpd, etc.

Comment: Windows 7 pro, Apache 2.4. Hope that helps. Sorry, I'm not so great with the terminology.

Comment: Try on Linux. Unfortunately, PHP on Windows doesn't work well on some situations. I suggest Vagrant as it's easy to setup.